# Why do newlines cause problems parsing strings in in as.formula()?

Tags: r

I can't understand the behavior of `as.formula()` when it encounters a newline in a string. For example,

```
ff <- y~1

fm1 <- paste0(deparse(ff),"+ x1 + x2")

as.formula(fm1)
```

Returns `y ~ 1 + x1 + x2` as expected. But if there is a newline in the string before `+`, `as.formula()` seems to silently truncate:

```
fm2 <- paste0(deparse(ff),"+x1
              +x2")

as.formula(fm2)
```

Returns `fm2` as `y ~ 1 + x1`, without `+ x2`. In the latter case, `fm2` is `"y ~ 1+x1\n              +x2"`.

Yes, one could say 'just don't do that', but this behavior was quite unexpected and ran without error, warning, or message.

Is there some internal parsing logic behind cutting off the string at `\n` and, more importantly, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Because a valid statement is present once the newline is encountered. Either ensure that the `+` is present before the new line, or strip the newline characters out. You also might want to look at `update.formula`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
x <- eval(parse(text=paste0(deparse(ff),"+x1+x2")))
```

The outcome can already be used as a model formula, without the need of `as.formula(x)`

Comment: This is useful. At least it gives an error if there is a carriage return between `+x1` and `+x2`. I'm curious why though.